# What is known about Celestial genes?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol 2,

> Ego says that, of all his children, Peter Quill is the only one whose DNA enabled him to have Celestial powers.

Since Ego is a planet, his intrinsic DNA is diverse and fragmented towards tasks specific to each organism on the planet, though some of those organisms may have Celestial powers.

**What is known about the unique aspects of a Celestial's DNA?**  Since Ego is the first Celestial that I recall after watching every Marvel movie, I wonder if the answer may have to come from the comics.

Comment: A bunch of celestials appeared in the first GotG film.

Comment: @ibid But, those weren't confirmed to be Celestials. Fans are just guessing. Remember, Ego said that he was alone.

Comment: http://marvel.com/universe/Celestials

Comment: I think that quote is more a reference to the flexibility and adaptability of Human DNA. That aside, I'm not really sure what you're asking. You can see from the movie that Peter could manipulate matter and energy on a molecular scale as long as he had a direct line to "The Light", and in the first GotG he could use an infinity stone without dying.

Comment: Although Ego has manifested himself in the shape of a planet, he actually isn't really a planet (at least not from *his* viewpoint). From *our* viewpoint, yes, Ego looks like a planet, quacks like a planet and is considered a "living planet".

Comment: ibid is correct. Gamora and the Collector both note Celestials (Knowhere and the video of one using the power stone) and both of their notes are verified by WoG.

Comment: Maybe, just like human "swimmers" only carry one 'Y' *or* 'X' chromosome, Celestials' swimmers each carry a different part of their DNA, and Peter was just the only one who got the 'C' chromosome.

Comment: Ego was probably just describing how Peter inherited his power.  When he talks about DNA, "it is metaphorical!!!"